# Tapfiliate React integration

Tags: reactjs, xmlhttprequest

I got struggle with Tapfiliate integration in react app. I use [this](https://github.com/Tapfiliate/tapfiliate-js).
Page click event is sent with no problem, but when trying to send conversion it returns 400 Bad request. I have all the needed data passed.

This is my request:

[image]

This is my response:

[image]

Request is called in async function which are called in `componentDidMount()`.

I just cant see whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who runs into this problem, when your script is live into a development environment, you can place "?tap_test=true" into your url to debug the problem. Tapfiliate will tell you exactly what is going on. In my case, I was forgetting to pass the comission type into the conversion function, before my success callback.